# syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -e $1 ] ; then 
mv $1 $1_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M) 
fi
exit 0
```

I requirement is to look for a file and if the file exits then rename the file and exit the prog, we need to rename only if the file exits

am getting the above mentioned error

Comment: Change your test to `if [ -e "$1" ];` and let us know if the problem persists.

Comment: To add to DopeGhoti's answer, use "$1" everywhere unless you know $1 will never include whitespace.  Use "sh -x" to trace the substitution; almost always you'll see something you didn't expect when you get an EOF error.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, bash variables should always be wrapped in double quotes.

For example, say $1 is `My File.txt`. Your script tries to do this:

`mv My File.txt My File.txt_201501010101`

which `mv` takes to mean that you want to move files `My`, `File.txt`, and `My` collectively to the destination `File.txt_201501010101`.

What you want instead is this:

`mv "My File.txt" "My File.txt_201501010101"`

See the following for more detail and other pitfalls to avoid:
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cp_.24file_.24target

P.S. `exit 0` at the end of a script is redundant. If the script finishes without errors then the exit status is implicitly 0.

Comment: Theres a Lesson Here: When Scripting use camelCase filenames or filenames with no spaces when scripting +1

Comment: @eyoung100 Wrong lesson. A naming convention to avoid having to quote filename variables works as long you control all files your script works with and you remember to do it every time you create or rename a file. Instead, just quote everything and you can work with any file you want and never have to worry about it.